# Why isn't this template resolved?

Tags: c++, templates

I don't get why this does not work

```
In member function ‘void Test_CB::testCB()’: 
error: no matching function for call to ‘calculateCB(USSM&, USSM&, NL&, double&, CD&)’
candidate is:
template<class T, class V> std::vector<CV> calculateCB(const T&, const T&, const NL&, double, const CD&)
```

The call is like this

```
USSM x1;
USSM x2;
NL x3;
double x4;
CD x5;
CV b = calculateCB<USSM, USM>(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5)[0];
```

I just described the types. They are created or returned in the proper way.

The template is declared as

```
template <class T, class V>
std::vector<CV> calculateCB(T const & x1,
                            T const & x2,
                            NL const & x3,
                            double x4,
                            CD const & x5);
```

and I also instantiate the template (as a desperation measure) as

```
template<>
std::vector<CV> calculateCB<USSM,USM>(USSM const & x1,
                                      USSM const & x2,
                                      NL const & x3,
                                      double x4,
                                      CD const & x5);
```

Note that the second template argument is an internally used variable in the template function.

Comment: That's not instantiation, that's specialisation (to instantiate, remove the `<>`). Can you post the **complete** compilation error?

Comment: Could you provide a small example that we can try to compile? Also, I'm curious what compiler are you using.

Comment: @Angew: That one is the complete compilation error. There are no errors before or after that. It's the only one.

Comment: @Mihai I am using gcc 4.6.3. It will take me a while to make an example. Give me some time.

Comment: @StefanoBorini The error you posted has no subject. It says "In member function X, candidate is Y." It has to say *something* about the error, e.g. "In member function X, *cannot determine overload for Z,* candidate is Y". There has to be a piece missing. The text you posted doesn't even contain the word "error."

Comment: @angew : oops. sorry. One sec

Comment: @angew: added the error. I just dropped the "no matching function". In any case, nothing else is available

Comment: @StefanoBorini, parts of your code compiles just fine with g++ 4.6.3(but crashes in runtime)([LWS example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/2keVVn$0))

Comment: What happens if you remove the instantiation/specialisation?

Comment: @soon: That's because `calculateCB` is not returning anything.

Comment: @JesseGood, yeah, it was just a note.

Comment: @soon I also tried that, and it indeed works. This makes the whole thing even more suspicious...

Comment: @soon I suspect the error is of a different nature, but g++ is complaining about something related but completely confusing. I am checking if the classes are actually declared at the moment

Comment: Thank you all people. It's always nice to see how you jump on a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, and it originated from an incorrect forward declaration of one of the classes I was using (NL). The actual name is way more complicated, and due to a case mismatch I could not see the difference.

I think that the error message of g++ should at least tell you where there's no match.

Comment: Temaplte error messages are very hard to do right. And sometimes there are several possible reasons for an error making it impossible to give an error message leading you in the right direction.

Comment: For easier to understand template-related error messages use clang instead of g++.